# PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Class &#039;Model Name&#039; not found

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I trying migration my project from yii1 to yii2.
I have some model function I make when I still use Yii1, is among others is generate id uniq function's, like this:

```
public static function generateID($tableName, $modelName) {
        $dateNow = date("Ymd");
        $checkLastID = $modelName::findBySql(
            "SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(id),-4) AS id FROM $tableName WHERE id LIKE '%$dateNow%'"
        )->one();
        $lastNumber = (int)substr($checkLastID["id"], 8,4);

        if($checkLastID["id"] == '') {
            $id = $dateNow.sprintf("%04s", 1);          
        } else {
            $lastNumber = $checkLastID["id"];
            $lastNumber++;
            if($lastNumber < 10) $id = $dateNow.sprintf("%04s", $lastNumber);
            elseif($lastNumber < 100) $id = $dateNow.sprintf("%04s", $lastNumber);
            elseif($lastNumber < 1000) $id = $dateNow.sprintf("%04s", $lastNumber);
            elseif($lastNumber < 10000) $id = $dateNow.sprintf("%04s", $lastNumber);
            else $id = $lastNumber;
        }
        return $id;
    }
```

and I access the function from controller like this:

```
$model->id = Helper::generateID('table_name', 'ModelName');
```

and than, show error when I want create data:

```
<pre>PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Class &#039;ModelName&#039; not found&#039; 

in C:\xampp\htdocs\kampunginggrispare.com\common\models\Helper.php:61

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleFatalError()
#1 {main}</pre>
```

But, If I change

```
$checkLastID = $modelName::findBySql("SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(id),-4) AS id FROM $tableName WHERE id LIKE '%$dateNow%'")->one();
```

to be:

```
$checkLastID = ModelName::findBySql("SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(id),-4) AS id FROM table_name WHERE id LIKE '%$dateNow%'")->one();
```

It's work, but doesn't work when I use Parameter like function above

In Yii1, not error,  but error in Yii2

Any body can help me ??

Thanks ...

Comment: Still error Mr. RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

Try to load $ModelName before use it in the `Helper` class. You can either

```
...

$dateNow = date("Ymd");
$className = '\common\models\\' . $modelName; // replace this with your model's namespace
$checkLastID = $className::findBySql(
    "SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(id),-4) AS id FROM $tableName WHERE id LIKE '%$dateNow%'"
)->one();

....
```

Or simply put your helper in the same namespace with the `$ModelName` (less recommended). I still don't understand the purpose of your `Helper` class.

Comment: wow ... this work Mr. Prabowo Murti
Helper class is collection of function that's I made for specific task, such as generate unique code etc ..

Comment: Great. I suggest you to read about `Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();` to get last inserted ID. If you found that my answer helps you, please kindly mark it as the accepted answer. Terima kasih :)

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 didn't find `ModelName` class.

Please read more about upgrading: [Upgrading from Version 1.1: Namespace](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-upgrade-from-v1.html#namespace) and [Yii2 autoloaders](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html).

Comment: Okay, I try first.